# echo ruturns nothing when referencing a class value

Tags: php

```
class bbsObj{
    var $num;
    var $dates;
    var $title;
    var $counts;
    function bbsObj($num, $datas, $title, $counts) {
        $this->num = $num;
        $this->dates = $num;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->counts = $counts;        
    }

    function getNum(){
        return $this->num;
    }
    function getDates(){
        return $this->dates;
    }
}   

$bbsObject = new bbsObj("1", "2012", "title", "0");
$data = array();
$data[0] = $bbsObject;
echo($data[0]->getNum());
```

is there any way to express arraylist < class >  type in php?

I believe echo should returns "1" but dont know why it returns nothing and shows nothing.

why am I getting nothing when I echoing?

Comment: Put some `var_dump`. Like `var_dump($bbsObject);`, `var_dump($data);`, etc ... It's called debugging.

Comment: Why the PHP 4 class definition code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its outputting `1`

Check it  -- http://codepad.org/zRqQe8RX

Check your `php` version

Comment: yes it does. i forgot to attach <br/> so I misunderstood 1blahblah as one output. it had to be as 1 <br/> blahblah.